# Alternate text colour for each word in a paragraph in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a text box of words in illustrator and I would like to alternate the text colour of each word, red, blue, red, blue and so forth. Can this be done in illustrator or another way? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking for an automated way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pre-built feature can achieve this unless you're willing to set the colours by hand on each word. Automating this is likely possible via scripting.

Comment: Thanks Lucian. I am new to Illustrator so I don;t think i will even consider scripting! At your suggestion I tried selecting individual words however I have copy pasted a whole bunch of words into a text box and now cannot seem to select individual words. It selects the whole text box. It is not grouped either. Any suggestions for this beginner?! Many thanks!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is not a one-on-one tutorial site, if you're new to AI, i guess you need to learn the basics first and do it by hand before considering advanced tricks. Youtube is full of AI training for beginners.